# Django makemessage error

Tags: python, django

**python manage.py makemessages -l en** returns this error - http://pastebin.com/GtXbT7ti
Can you help me?

Comment: did you save your file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I think, yes. I use Sublime with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Set at the beginning your files, something like

```
#! coding:utf-8
```

Seems like you had Russian or else non-ASCii chars in your file.